# Are PHP extensions just "shell cases" for real libraries?

Tags: php, shell, php-extension

If this is true and PHP extensions run shell commands in the background, why not just use `shell_exec` instead? Would there be any difference? I'm under the impression that PHP extension are usually written by newbs because they are full of bugs. For example the imagick extension :/ So why not communicate with the library directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, absolutely not. Most PHP extensions interface directly with a C library, and [imagick is no exception](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/master/imagick.c).

The shoddiness of the imagick extension is entirely the fault of the ImageMagick library itself.